# Custom AuthenticationManager not used in Spring Security 6

Tags: authentication, spring-security

For my Spring Boot (3.1.) / Spring Security (6.1.0) application I need to support multiple custom authentication methods. So I created my own AuthenticationManager with two custom AuthenticationProviders.

The AuthenticationProviders are not getting called and I just get a 403.

My security configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        var builder = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
        // Two AuthenticationProvider implementations that are not called
        builder.authenticationProvider(new AuthProvider1());
        builder.authenticationProvider(new AuthProvider2());
        var authManager = builder.build();

        return http.authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz.anyRequest().authenticated())
                .authenticationManager(authManager) 
                .build();
    }
}
```

When I call my dummy RestController at `GET /products`, this is de `debug` log output:

```
13:31:51.540 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] - Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
13:31:51.540 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
13:31:51.540 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Detected StandardServletMultipartResolver
13:31:51.540 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Detected AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver
13:31:51.540 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Detected FixedThemeResolver
13:31:51.541 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator@3b1247f7
13:31:51.541 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager@6cd3032
13:31:51.541 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - enableLoggingRequestDetails='false': request parameters and headers will be masked to prevent unsafe logging of potentially sensitive data
13:31:51.541 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Completed initialization in 1 ms
13:31:51.547 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Securing GET /products
13:31:51.550 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
13:31:51.552 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
13:31:51.562 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache - Saved request http://localhost:8080/products to session
13:31:51.562 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint - Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
13:31:51.563 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - Did not store empty SecurityContext
13:31:51.564 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - Did not store empty SecurityContext
13:31:51.564 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
13:31:51.566 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Securing GET /error
13:31:51.566 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
13:31:51.566 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
13:31:51.566 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Secured GET /error
13:31:51.572 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - Did not store anonymous SecurityContext
13:31:51.573 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - Did not store anonymous SecurityContext
13:31:51.573 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
```

Any idea why my AuthenticationManager with AuthenticationProviders are not being used? I know there are alternatives to this approach, like writing my own security filters. I was just hoping I could use this straightforward looking approach that seems to be the right solution for having multiple authentication strategies.

Similar issue is discussed here in the comments:
https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter

The Spring Security docs suggest this is the right approach:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/architecture.html#servlet-authentication-authenticationmanager

Comment: my guess is because you have not selected any authentication method, you have just said that they should be authenticated, but not how or by what?

Answer (score -1):

We had a similar issue when we moved from Spring Security 5.7.3 to 6.1.1. The custom authentication manager was created in earlier versions, but never failed until we moved to 6.x

We had to explicitly set the **ParentAuthenticationManager** to the custom AuthenticationManager in your SecurityConfig class.

```
   private void setParentAuthenticationManager(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception
    {
        var authManagerBuilder = httpSecurity.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);

        // authManagerBuilder.eraseCredentials(false);
        authManagerBuilder.parentAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
    }

    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager()
    {
      . . . 
    }
```

Note: In our configurations a number of custom AuthenticationProviders are provided.